# Leap year and symbol used

Tags: swift, symbols, 2-digit-year

How do I determine numbers divisible by 4? I'm trying to apply a leap year.
I see a lot of solutions that show a '%' symbol. What does it mean?

Comment: That's the remainder (modulo) operator: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID64

Comment: So you could do `if number % 4 == 0 { /// number is divisible by 4 }`

Comment: If you want to check is a year is a leap year you can simply check if the range of days in year is equal to 366. `Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .year, for: Date())!.count == 366`

Answer (score 0):

To check if a number `x` is divisible by any other number `y`, you can use the modulo operator to get the remainder of the division (it should be `0`).

```
x % y == 0
```